# I am designing a heater and i want to hold the nichrome wire inside a frame, what can be used?

Tags: heat-protection

Can i use cement for holding the wire ? Or some other material is required.

Comment: If you can find a non-corrosive cement.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I am asking for the cement used in making house. I don't know it is non-corrosive or not, can i use that ?

Comment: Portland cement is very caustic.

Comment: Portland cement protects steel against corrosion. That is why reinforced concrete structures are so popular and long-lived. But portland cement is not very heat resistant. I have read about this a bit. Will share what I have learned. Calcium aluminate cement is very heat resistant. A mix of calcium aluminate cement and aluminum oxide abrasive media would be very heat resistant. Or you can also make a heat resistant cement using sodium silicate as a binder for aluminum oxide abrasive media. This will not set up very fast unless you expose it to CO2 or heat it up, e.g., with a torch.

Comment: if your supplies are coming from a hardware store, plaster of paris might work better than cement.

Comment: Without a diagram, it is not clear to me what the arrangement of the wire is or where you want to hold it. However, if the need is to support the wire along its length then you could use more pieces of Nichrome wire and have them electrically isolated. How hot is the wire intended to get?

Comment: What about winding it around a mica plate?

Answer (score 1):

Go visit [Cotronics](http://www.cotronics.com/vo/cotr/) web site. This is exactly what they do. They supply forms, epoxies, ceramics, etc., exactly for this kind of purpose. Write them about exactly what you want to achieve and they will help you select the right products to try.

---

You may want a form to wind your nichrome wire or ribbon around. Regardless of the form, there are high temperature ceramic and epoxy adhesives you can use for those or one of your own design. Both the forms and the epoxies and ceramic adhesives are similar to the materials you will find in those large, high wattage resistor blocks.

Examine the materials for thermal resistance. And some of these materials also have very high bulk electrical resistivity to avoid current leakage, but it doesn't sound as though you need that. (Almost all of them have pretty high resistance, regardless.)

Comment: You might wind them on mica sheets.  I see them in surplus places sometimes and Amazon.  An adhesive might not be needed.

Comment: @RobertEndl Yes, I've seen mica used in toasters often enough and they don't use adhesives for that. But we don't know the application here, as the OP didn't say much. So it's hard to know.